# jekyll blog new line (minimal-mistake)

Tags: yaml, jekyll

jekyll blog(minimal-mistakes thema) has a space to introduce myself.
[image]

I want to write on two lines in this space.
For example

```
hello
world
```

I know that to edit this page, i need to touch the _config.yml file.

```
# Site Author
author:
  name             : "Choi Young-jin"
  avatar           : "/assets/images/images/avatar.png"

  bio              : "**^^**" <-----------Parts to change

  42 intra ID: yochoi
  location         : "Seoul"
  email            : "amateur.toss@gmail.com"
  links:
    - label: "Email"
      icon: "fas fa-fw fa-envelope-square"
      # url: "amateur.toss@gmail.com"
    - label: "GitHub"
      icon: "fab fa-fw fa-github"
      url: "https://github.com/amateurtoss"
```

The escape character does not work.

```
  bio: "hello\nworld"
```

What if I want to show the string in two lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it's markdown, so you should do

```yaml
  bio: |-
    hello

    world
```

(That's a YAML block scalar, which is interpreted literally and ends with the next item on the same or lesser indentation level as `bio`)

You can of course also do

```yaml
  bio: "hello\n\nworld"
```

But it's less obvious what happens here.

Comment: @AMATEUR_TOSS YAML multiline could be so obscure that someone kind enough actually wrote a page demo'ing it: https://yaml-multiline.info/, it's a worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML in the bio string, so you can simply use a HTML linebreak:

```
  bio: "hello<br>world"
```

The above is the only way in which I managed to have a single line break. All other options lead to either no line break or an empty line between the two lines.